# Trying to add second button on Squarespace product page

Tags: jquery, html, css, page-refresh, squarespace

Link to the page in question at the bottom.

Squarespace has an "Add to Cart" button by default on product pages, but I'd like to add a "View Cart" button right next to it.

I've successfully added it but for some reason it only shows after refreshing the page. If I navigate to a different page then go back to the product page I was just on, it's gone again. If I refresh, it shows.

This happens on Safari, Chrome, and Firefox, regular and incognito/private browsing, as well as on mobile (iOS). So I'm assuming it's not just a cache issue and the button is only displaying after a page refresh.

I had to add some extra code to the "Code Injection" field to get the button to show as well as some CSS. I'll paste everything below.

https://willryan.co/shop/gulfshores

(To see my problem, refresh the page. Then navigate to a different product under "Shop," and refresh again. Note how the grey "View Cart" button only shows after refresh)

**EDIT: Going to Design > Style Editor > and unchecking "Enable Ajax loading" seems to have fixed it. Not sure if there are downsides to disabling this...**

---

**CODE INJECTION (also includes code for a back to top button I implemented)**

```
<!-- Add Checkout Button after every Add to Cart button -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    $("<a class='checkoutbutton' href='/commerce/show-cart'>VIEW CART</a>").insertAfter(".sqs-add-to-cart-button");        
});
</script>

<!-- Icon for Back to Top --->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<!--- For Back to Top Button ---->
<script>
   $(document).ready(function () {
       $(window).scroll(function () {
           if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
               $('.scrollup').fadeIn();
           } else {
               $('.scrollup').fadeOut();
           }
       });
       $('.scrollup').click(function () {
           $("html, body").animate({
               scrollTop: 0
           }, 600);
           return false;
       });
   });
</script>
```

---

**CUSTOM CSS**

```
/* Add checkout buton after add to cart */
 .checkoutbutton {
   font-family: oswald;
   font-size: 16px;
   color: rgba(170,170,170,1);
   font-weight: 400;
   font-style: normal;
   text-align: center;
   width: 250px;
   text-decoration: none;
   padding: 13px 30px;
   margin: 10px;
   border: 2px;
   border-style: solid;
 }

 .checkoutbutton:hover {
   color: #fff;
   background-color: rgba(170,170,170,1);
   text-decoration: none;
   border: 2px;
   border-style: solid;
   border-color: rgba(170,170,170,1); 
 }

.scrollup {
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   opacity: 0.4;
   position: fixed;
   bottom: 2%;
   right: 2%;
   display: none;
   /* text-indent: -9999px; */
   color: #aaaaaa;
 }

#site {
     max-width: 1400px; /*Adjust as desired.*/
     margin-right: auto;
     margin-left: auto;
 }



 /*Prevent header growing in height infinitely.*/
 #header {
     margin-top: 5%;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

In Squarespace, when your custom Javascript only works after a page refresh, it most likely has to do with [Squarespace's AJAX loading](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000253288-Ajax-loading), as you determined:

> Occasionally, Ajax may conflict with embedded custom code or anchor
>   links. Ajax can also interfere with site analytics, logging hits on
>   the first page only.

You are correct that [**disabling AJAX for your template**](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000253288-Ajax-loading#toc-enable-or-disable-ajax) often fixes the issue (though it also disables AJAX loading). Another solution is to wrap your custom Javascript in this:

```
window.addEventListener("mercury:load", function(){
   // do stuff
});
```

Note: some users have reported mixed results with this method. It personally worked for me recently, but other factors may be an influence.

Comment: Hey Brandon, thanks for responding.

You actually responded to another comment of mine in another thread about this.

Disabling Ajax does work, but now I'm curious if I can solve this without disabling it.

Regarding the mercury load code, maybe I'm using it incorrectly? I pasted that chunk within a <script></script>, and added my button code within the tag, but I didn't have any luck. Does it need to be injected on a per-page basis? Anything else I might be missing? 

Thanks for your help!

Comment: In cases like this, I would start simple. See if you can get a basic `console.log()` statement to work consistently on initial load and on each subsequent page load using the `mercury:load` event. If you can, then slowly work through integrating your other code into it until you find the problem. But if something simple doesn't work, it may be that some templates have additional factors in play.